# Getting bad File Description error when reading from CSV file

Tags: rust

I'm opening and reading from file like this

```rust
        let file_result = File::open(&one_csv_file);
        let file = match file_result {
            Ok(file) => file,
            Err(error) => match error.kind() {
                ErrorKind::NotFound => match File::create(&one_csv_file) {
                    Ok(fc) => fc,
                    Err(e) => {panic!("Problem with creating file: {key}: {:?}", e)},
                },
                other_error => {
                    panic!("[ ERR ] Problem opening the file: {:?}", other_error);
                }
            },
        };
        let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(file);
        for record in reader.records() {
            let mut url = String::new();
            match record {
                Ok(v) => {last_number = v[0].parse().unwrap();
                    url = v[1].to_string()},
                Err(e) => {last_number = 0; panic!("{:?}",e)},
            }

            if url.contains("https://") {
                url_list.push(url);
            }
        }
```

But opening the file is panicking and getting this error on this line `Err(e) => {last_number = 0; panic!("{:?}",e)},`:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error(Io(Os { code: 9, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Bad file descriptor" }))
```

Am I opening the file wrong? Should I open it for writing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad File Descriptor with Linux Socket write() Bad File Descriptor C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258781/bad-file-descriptor-with-linux-socket-write-bad-file-descriptor-c)

Comment: I think no, its little bit different, also language is different

Comment: It's very likely that some other part of your code is bugged and closing a file descriptor that doesn't belong to it. Create an MCVE.

Comment: I have two places where I'm opening the file. I put them both to a new scope, so when scope ends, resources become free. But the error is still there.

Comment: i tried to execute it more times, sometimes it goes without error

Comment: Does this error happens because the file Im trying read it empty?

Comment: You try to open the file for reading, but if that fails then you open it for writing (with `create`)! So in your case the file probably doesn't exist, gets opened for writing, then reading from it fails.